# Is passing a method as a string param to a directive not a bad thing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

While discovering directives a bumped on the following:

```
<div ng-app="twitterApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div enter>Roll over to load more tweets</div>
  </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('twitterApp', []);   
app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.loadMoreTweets = function () {
    alert("Loading tweets!");
  }
})

app.directive("enter", function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
      scope.loadMoreTweets();
    })
  }
})
```

They say:
"it is better practice to decouple the loadMoreTweets() method entirely by passing it to the directive as a string parameter in the view, and retrieving it from the attrs parameter in the directive."

so it becomes:

```
<div ng-app="twitterApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
     div enter="loadMoreTweets()">Roll over to load more tweets</div>
  </div>
</div>

app.directive("enter", function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
       scope.$apply(attrs.enter);
    })
  }
})
```

but is that not going back to:

```
     **<div onClick="loadMoreTweets()">Roll over to load more tweets</div>**
```

This confuses me, this way JavaScript gets mixed again with HTML. And aren't we trying to avoid that? We use addEventListener() and attachEvent() these day's or do I see this wrong.

Comment: While i understand the differences between imperative and declarative programmming, i feel my own writing/language skills are not up to scratch to explain the difference in a sufficient capacity.

Thus i'll link you to a good article:

http://mikecr.it/ramblings/angularjss-declarative-markup

Comment: @clark Pan I wrote up my bit before reading the article to try and do it fresh, but ended up agreeing on most of the points.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my two cents.

It's not that we're trying to necessarily remove all script calls from the HTML it's that we don't want to depend on the HTML for the script to work.  This way the HTML can be replaced and we know the plumbing (AngularJS in this case) will still work.  You don't want to reference anything from the angular side of the wall (controllers, services) that requires knowledge of the DOM (directives aside).

It creates a clear separation of your business logic (which can then be tested) and your views (which pretty much require human testing... until AI gets better).

There are cases such as the click event where there is no avoiding having the view have some knowledge of the underlying script, if one uses the other they are connected.  The nice thing is on the Angular side you just need to keep your interface the same and you can change the actual implementation without messing up the view (it's always about the interface and being able to replace dependencies).

Basically writing this directive so it uses the parameter to potentially extend it's functionality to call arbitrary functions instead of tying it to only doing one specific task will avoid the need to duplicate and tweak this code (Don't Repeat Yourself, DRY).

Long and short of it de-coupling is important but some knowledge of an interface between parts that work with each other is always necessary.  Sometimes the advantage of avoiding code repetition (therefore lots of places to update if there's problems/tweaks) out-weighs the desire to keep any knowledge of the underlying structure hidden from the view.

Keep in mind the addEventListener/attachEvent is still what's happening here, see the element.bind call, this would still allow for multiple event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Decoupling HTML and app logic was a good idea with typical web pages, where there the HTML was written by web designers and then the resulting work was enhanced by adding little bits of JavaScript.

When creating SPAs with complex view and presentation logic all over the place, most of your HTML is written by programmers. Angular provides data-binding features with default directives for us programmers to use and I deem it wise to use them. Even when you couple HTML and angular scope object together tightly-Angular fails silently on non-existent scope properties. So in most cases it won't cause big problems if there is a mismatch.

If you are paranoid that your HTML bindings are not proper, I think it should be possible to write angular service for debugging which would check up on all directives and warn you if some of the bindings are bound to undefined or null properties.